# Check box Checked state is Not working in Custom paging in Devexpress Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am using Devexpress gridview. In that I am implementing the custom paging. After implementing the custom paging a checkbox checked state is not working in the Gridview.
If I check any row in the First page when I go to second page and if I come back to again first page, my previous checked column is not in a checked state.

Can any one help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: are you familiar with PostBacks and ViewState.. ? this sounds more like a PostBack Issue..can you show the code on how you are persisting the checked state..? and how you are checking it when load / populating the Gridview..?

Answer (score 0):

You are reloading page after pagination so you are losing your context where checkboxes are checked. It is my first shoot, without code it is hard to say more pissible issues of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for post backs then checked checkbox will lose its state i guess. Do this store checked row number in a hidden field and then once you go to next page and come back get values from hidden fields and check your checked check boxes